# How can you create a depth raster from a DTM and a polygon in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, dem

I have a DTM raster and a flood outline in polygon format - how do I create a depth raster for the flood outline (i.e. flood level minus DTM level)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, the QGIS Raster Calculator will do what you want. For some examples that touch on your problem see:

http://spatialgalaxy.net/2012/01/25/using-the-qgis-raster-calculator/

I think you would then clip the output raster using your flood polygon.

N.

Comment: Thanks - this has worked perfectly - have moved companies, completely new to QGIS have worked exclusively in Arc previously

Answer (score 3):

I've run into this same problem in the past. I'm sorry but I don't use QGIS very often so my answer is going to use [Whitebox Geospatial Analysis Tools](http://www.uoguelph.ca/~hydrogeo/Whitebox/) and I'm sure you can find the equivalent tools in QGIS to perform the same task. The basic idea is to interpolate a flood surface based on the elevations from the DEM that coincide with the perimeter of the flood polygon and then to difference the DEM from this flood surface. This workflow also assumes that your flood polygon is not a contour line (i.e. that it has been mapped, say off of an air photo, and that the outline doesn't have a single elevation). If you've mapped your flood extent, it is very likely that the edges of the polygon will not have a single elevation, but rather a range of elevations. If the flood polygon was in fact derived as a contour, the workflow can be greatly simplified by using a raster calculator expression.

1. Use the '[Erase polygon from raster](http://www.uoguelph.ca/~hydrogeo/Whitebox/Help/ErasePolygonFromRaster.html)' tool to remove the flood polygon from the DEM, i.e. to replace grid cells contained within the flood zone with a NoData value.
2. Use the '[Fill missing data holes](http://www.uoguelph.ca/~hydrogeo/Whitebox/Help/FillMissingDataHoles.html)' tool to interpolate the flood surface based on the elevations along the flood polygon's perimeter. This is of course an estimate of the flood surface. If you needed a greater level of accuracy here, you'd need to perform hydraulic modelling, but based on your question, I'm guess this will suffice. Also, there are any number of interpolators that could be used for this task.
3. Difference the original DEM from flood surface raster. If you wish, you can use the '[Set NoData value](http://www.uoguelph.ca/~hydrogeo/Whitebox/Help/SetNoData.html)' tool to remove all of the zero values outside of the flood zone from the raster. Values within the flood polygon will be flood depths.

Comment: Thank you for the response - the reply below has been straightforward without  the need for a plugin, appreciate the reply

Comment: @USER4321 I'm not sure what you mean by plugin.